# How to clear cache after a Meteor hot code push

Tags: javascript, caching, meteor, browser

I have evidence of Meteor caching an old version of a template helper .js file and can't find any strategy to remedy it.

Just after a hot code push, a template will load (a form) and but the corresponding .js file that contains the form validation will be the older version, causing the form to never be valid.

Most everyone on my team uses Mac/Chrome and this bug is cleared by clicking 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload'.

Does anyone else experience this? Any suggestions?

Comment: A few questions - what version of Meteor are you using, and are you using Meteor's [appcache](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/appcache) package?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not using appcache, and Meteor 1.3.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution
https://forums.meteor.com/t/clean-up-your-meteor-package-cache/38471

Install cleaner:

meteor npm install -g meteor-cleaner

and run:

meteor clean-package-cache [options]